# WebKit width not updating?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, width

I have a piece of code which runs on window resize. I am pulling the *`width`*, and the *`outerWidth`* of a input text element.

This process works fine in every browser, except Webkit, which returns the proper result from *`outerWidth`*, but the result from *`width`* **never changes** from the on load original.

This is actual console output from my script when resizing the browser window (This is Chrome, but the same happens in Safari 4):

```
outerWidth: 772
width: 772
outerWidth: 773
width: 772
outerWidth: 773
width: 772
outerWidth: 794
width: 772
outerWidth: 794
width: 772
outerWidth: 815
width: 772
outerWidth: 815
width: 772
outerWidth: 820
width: 772
outerWidth: 837
width: 772
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Do you know why it happens? And most importantly, do you know how to work around it? :)

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post some code? I just tried with Safari 4 and both work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my test case. Both seem to work as expected (Safari 4).

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    input {
      width: 50%;
      height: 2em;
      font-size: 1em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="w" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="ow" />
  </p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init(){
      $('#w').val($('#w').width());
      $('#ow').val($('#ow').outerWidth());
    }
    $(function(){
      init();

      $(window).resize(function(){
        init();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works great in Safari 4. Older jQuery version perhaps?